# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k]{\prod_\limits{k=0}^{n}a_k^{\lambda_k} }= \ell =\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $a_n\to \ell\neq 0$ is a converging sequence of positive real numbers and $\{\lambda_n\}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda_k = \infty$.

Then show that, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k]{\prod_\limits{k=0}^{n}a_k^{\lambda_k} }= \ell =\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

I have no clue on how to start.

Comment: If it were allowed : take $$\lambda_k=n\delta_{k,m},m\in\mathbb{N}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [General Cesaro summation with weight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440333/general-cesaro-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1-sum-limitsk-0n-lambda-k?rq=1) we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k]{\prod_\limits{k=0}^{n}a_k^{\lambda_k} }
= \exp\Big(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k \ln(a_k)\Big) 
=\exp(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \ln(a_n))=\ell$$

Answer (score 11):

The question is equivalent to:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{\lambda _k}\ln ({a_k})} }}{{\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{\lambda _k}} }} = \ln l$$
Since ${\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{\lambda _k}} }$ increases to $+\infty$, Stolz's theorem immediately gives the reult.